# Apache redirect if string contains anything other than letters and numbers

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

So I have a rewrite condition, where it takes the `%1` from the previous line, and should redirect if the string contains anything other than letters and numbers. But, for some reason, it works if the string only begins and ends with letters or numbers (Allowing the middle to be anything)

Heres the condition:

```
RewriteCond %1 !^[A-Z0-9]+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/nomatch
```

So, in my case, it wont redirect if `%1` is `hdsuf38//*&hdsfghj73`

Anyone know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two changes

- Add small letters as well to the character sequence.
- Add the anchor `$` so that the matching is continued till the end of string

Regex can be

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/vW1yH2/1)

Rule as

```
RewriteCond %1 !^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/nomatch
```

Comment: Hmm, I thought the NC made it non case sensitive

Comment: I'll implement it in about half hour and get back to you :D